# PHP multidimensional associative array value update

Tags: php

I am trying to update a value based one some condition but it doesn't update.

Here is my code

```
     foreach($div as $key=>$d){ 
        if(!$d['playingDate']){
           // SOME CODE GOES HERE.

        }else{

            // THIS CODE DEOSN'T UPDATE THE WEEKDAY
            $div[$key]['date']['weekday'] = $d['weekday'];
        }
     }
```

My sample data is like this

```
.......
{
id: 3209,
playingDate: "2019-01-27",
playingTime: "19:00",
weekday: "Mån",
date: {
    id: 94,
    gameLength: "90",
    startingDate: "2018-12-24",
    startingTime: "19:00",
    weekday: "Mån"
},
{
id: 3209,
playingDate: "2019-01-27",
playingTime: "19:00",
weekday: "Sun",
date: {
    id: 94,
    gameLength: "90",
    startingDate: "2018-12-24",
    startingTime: "19:00",
    weekday: "Mån"
},
```

as you can see the second item has `weekday Sun` so it should update the data.weekday to `Sun` as well but it doesn't.

Comment: ```$d['date']['startingTime'] = $d['playingTime'];``` whats this line ???

Comment: No, I edited the answer now. Please see

Comment: can you check and execute the code here - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7844a85085e58bb53b98411d6f8a8929398604cb  -  its working fine and the value is updated.

Comment: In your sample data, there is no 'date' array with default value "Mån"

Comment: added the date array also, and its updating fine. check here - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ce3529586552795e4483ef7d12868fefa5bb22f

Comment: Yes, it works there but why it is not working for in production :(

Comment: if you are showing the full code then will try to fix. There is no issue in the code you shared :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This is the main code. all others are extra code. I will let you know if it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this

> $div[$key]['date']['weekday'] = date('l', strtotime($d['playingTime']));

this will automatically return your weekday within the `$div` that you use. let me know if this helps.

and for these kind of errors, try dumping the array so you can see if all the information will be within the array.

Answer (score -1):

You close the `foreach` before the `else` statement. It must return an error.

Add this code at the top of your script to help you debug php :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: No, it all ok no errors. Foreach loops is ok in my code

Comment: `foreach($div as $key=>$d){ 
        if(!$d['playingDate']){
           // SOME CODE GOES HERE.
            }
        }else{` 
Your `else` condition is outside the `foreach`, so not after the `if`. Try a simple echo in your else, it shouldn't work.

Comment: Cannot see what you wrote